# Is an object's pressure on a surface, affected by the type of surface?

Tags: pressure, metals, elements

Is an object's pressure on a surface, affected by the type of surface. For example, if a chunk of metal gave a pressure of $2800 \ pa$ on a table, would it still give a pressure of $2800$ on dust/sand, and what if the sand had iron oxide, such as on Mars (not including the difference of gravity)? Would that change the pressure? If it does change the pressure would the pressure be more or less than on the table?

Comment: Try here @ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure#Definition  .